# Placing 2 divs side by side in 1 div with float affects background color inside that div

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to build a website for my clan but I'm having trouble with Float in CSS. Here's what I'm trying to do

I'm trying to create 2 divs side by side in 1 div but it keeps on disappearing the background color of the clanoverlay class. I'm getting really confused if I should use display: inline-block; because float: left; seems to make the background color dissapear. Here's an example:

```css
div.colum2 {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}

div.clanboard {
 font-family: SupercellMagic;
 font-size: 200%;
 color: white;
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
 -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #636a7c;
}
div.clanboardoverlay {
 background-color: #e4eff4;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

div.claninfo {
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 35%;
 padding: 10px 40px; 
 font-family: SupercellMagic;
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
 -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

div.clanmembers {
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 35%;
 padding: 10px 40px; 
 font-family: SupercellMagic;
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
 -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: black;">

<div class=colum1>
 <div class=clanboard>
  <center>Clan [in progress]</center>
  <div class=clanboardoverlay>
   <div class=claninfo style="float: left;">
   <img src="/imgsrc/badge.png" width="75">
   <span style="font-family: SupercellMagic;">ReAdY 4 War</span><br>
   <span style="color: grey; font-size: 17px;">Members: </span><span style="color: white; font-size: 20;">46/50</span>
   <hr><span style="color: black; font-size: 15;">looking for good loyal players ready to expand and have fun</span><hr>
   <span style="color: white; font-size: 15;">Clan Score</span><span style="color: white; float: right; font-size: 15;"><img src="/imgsrc/trophy.png" width="30px" style="vertical-align: text-top;">9828</img></span>
   <hr>
   <span style="color: white; font-size: 15;">Donations/week:</span><span style="color: white; float: right; font-size: 15;">1244</span>
   <hr>
   <span style="color: white; font-size: 15;">Type:</span><span style="color: white; float: right; font-size: 15;">Invite Only</span>
   <hr>
   <span style="color: white; font-size: 15;">Required trophies:</span><span style="color: white; float: right; font-size: 15;">0</span>
   <hr>
   <span style="color: white; font-size: 15;">Location:</span><span style="color: white; float: right; font-size: 15;">International</span>
   <hr>
   <span style="color: white; font-size: 15;">Clan tag:</span><span style="color: white; float: right; font-size: 15;">#G2PRPQ</span>
   </div>
   <div class=clanmembers style="float: right;">
   Just a test :)
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Link: http://ready4war.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow try to not put the CSS in your HTML(that is not recommended)

why you not try to use flex-box?

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
   background-color:green;
}
.child{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">

</div>
<div class="child">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the floats for the parent of the two floated elements. You can use `overflow: hidden;` or

```
.clanboardoverlay {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```